# Hourly groups/Slots from Shift start time and end time in Microsoft excel or Power Query

Tags: excel-formula, powerquery

I am trying to create Hourly gropus from Shift start time and end time in Microsoft excel or Power Query

I have 2 columns Start time and End time, And I intending to create Group/Bucket of Hours for worked between between specific Time Slots

For Example :

| Start Time | End Time | Mins Between 6a-7a | Mins between 7a-11a | Mins Btwn 11a-3p | Min btwn 3p-7p | Mins Btwn 7p-11p | Mins Btwn 11p-12a | Mins Btwn 12a-6a |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9:00:00 PM | 7:00:00 AM | 60 | 0 | NA | 0 | 120 | 60 | 360 |
| 8:00:00 AM | 4:00:00 PM | 0 | 180 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I have used Nested if Statements however  I am finding it challenging with the overnight nights and some of the Shifts which fall in between two time . I was hoping if we can write a Custom Column formula in Power query

Code used for Columns header "Mins Between 6a-7a":

```
=IF( AND($Start time>$6am,$End Time<$7am),
  (End time - Start time)*1440,
  IF(AND($Start time>=6am,$Start Time<=7am), (7am-Start time)*1440,0)
+ IF(AND($End time>=6a,$End time<=7p),($End time-6a)*1440,0)
+ IF(AND($Start time<=6a,$End time>=7p),60,0) )
```

Comment: Could you share the nested if statement(s) so we can direct you in the right way?

Comment: Thanks..I have just copied the formula across for the first column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In powerquery

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Start Time", type time}, {"End Time", type time}}),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom.1", each if Duration.TotalMinutes([End Time]-[Start Time]) <0 then Duration.TotalMinutes([End Time]-[Start Time]) +1440 else Duration.TotalMinutes([End Time]-[Start Time])),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Custom", each List.Times([Start Time], [Custom.1], #duration(0, 0, 1, 0))),
// add your columns here in same format
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "6-7AM", each List.Count( List.Select([Custom], each _ >= #time (6,0,0) and _ < #time(7,0,0)))),
#"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom2", "7-11am", each List.Count( List.Select([Custom], each _ >= #time (8,0,0) and _ < #time(11,0,0)))),
#"Added Custom4" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom3", "11pm-12am", each List.Count( List.Select([Custom], each _ >= #time (23,0,0) and _ < #time(24,0,0)))),
#"Added Custom5" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom4", "12am-6am", each List.Count( List.Select([Custom], each _ >= #time (0,0,0) and _ < #time(6,0,0)))),
// remove extra columns after
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom5",{"Custom.1", "Custom"})
in  #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you so much, Works like a treat. I kept using List.Sum instead of List.Count